# Python PySNMP: unable to fetch OID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysnmp

I seem to be unable to fetch SNMP using pysnmp.
Same result with python2 and 3.
The device uses SNMP v2.

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.5597.30.0.2.2 = No Such Object currently exists 
at this OID
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.5597.30.0.2.4 = No Such Object currently exists 
at this OID
```

While snmpwalk works fine:

```
snmpwalk -v1 -cpublic 10.0.1.8 1.3.6.1.4.1.5597.30.0.2.2
iso.3.6.1.4.1.5597.30.0.2.2.0 = INTEGER: 1
```

This is my code:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
import time

SNMP_HOST = '10.0.1.8'
SNMP_PORT = 161
SNMP_COMMUNITY = 'public'

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(
cmdgen.CommunityData(SNMP_COMMUNITY),
cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((SNMP_HOST, SNMP_PORT)),
'1.3.6.1.4.1.5597.30.0.2.2',
'1.3.6.1.4.1.5597.30.0.2.4'
)

# Check for errors and print out results
if errorIndication:
  print(errorIndication)
else:
  if errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (
      errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
      errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
      )
    )
  else:
    for name, val in varBinds:
      print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `GET iso.3.6.1.4.1.5597.30.0.2.2`, while snmpwalk reports that only OID `iso.3.6.1.4.1.5597.30.0.2.2.0` exists.

Try this code (as taken from [this example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/snmp-versions.html#snmpv2c)). It uses the newer and more concise pysnmp API, though your code should work as well once you fix the OID you query for.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData('public'),
           UdpTransportTarget(('10.0.1.8', 161)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.5597.30.0.2.2.0')))
)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

Comment: Thanks, now i seem to get values back. There was a ) missing after ObjectType(...)